# Fill NAs with Previous non-NA available value R

Tags: r, text

I am trying to fill the NA values with the non-NA previous available in a set of data of 3 million rows. At the moment I am able to do it but it takes about 3hrs.

Constrains - I cannot use any library, it has to be done with R basic

Data - My data looks as following (Extract)

[Data Extract As Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr9LN.png)

At the moment I have been using the following code

```
CHARDIF <- diff(VERINDEX_VEC)

k = 1
for (j in VERINDEX_VEC){
  #when value is in vector calculate difference to next value and copy VER. 
Special cases for First and Last value
  ifelse(j == 1, ALL_POS$C01[j:CHARDIF[k]] <- ALL_POS$C01[j],
         ifelse(j == max(VERINDEX_VEC), ALL_POS$C01[j:max(as.numeric
(row.names(ALL_POS)))] <- ALL_POS$C01[j],ALL_POS$C01[j:(j+CHARDIF[k]-1)] <- 
ALL_POS$C01[j]))
  k = k + 1
}
```

As you can see I have a vector with the non-NA positions, and then I calculate the difference between the positions, and that helps me to select the range I want to paste as I know when the next non-NA value is happening.

Does anyone have a better solution? a faster one in particular

Comment: Just use `na.locf(VERINDEX_VEC)`

Comment: `na.locf`is not in base, however you might want to consider getting rid of the for loop, instead take a look at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/lapply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is doing a lot of calculating and memory allocation every time it loops. To decrease time we want to decrease how much work the loop does each iteration.

I'm not 100% clear on your problem, but I think I've got the gist of it. It sounds like you just want to take the last non-NA value and copy it into the row with the NA value. We can use a pair or indexes to do this.

In the following method all of the memory is already pre-allocated before I enter the loop. The only memory action is to replace a value (NA) with another value. Other then that operation there is a check to see if the value is NA and there is an addition operation on the index. In order to get significantly faster on this problem you would need to use c-optimized vector functions (probably from a package/library).

To use the previous value to fill NA:

```
# Fill with previous non-NA value
VERINDEX_VEC <- c(NA,"A1","A2",NA,NA,"A3",NA)
VERINDEX_VEC
# [1] NA   "A1" "A2" NA   NA   "A3" NA  

non_na_positions <- which(!is.na(VERINDEX_VEC))
# If the first value is NA we need to fill with NA until we hit a known value...
if(is.na(VERINDEX_VEC[1])){
  non_na_positions <- c(NA,non_na_positions)
}

index = 1

for(i in 1:length(VERINDEX_VEC)){
  if(is.na(VERINDEX_VEC[i])) {
    VERINDEX_VEC[i] <- VERINDEX_VEC[non_na_positions[index]]
  } else {
    index <- index + 1
  }
}

VERINDEX_VEC
# [1] NA   "A1" "A2" "A2" "A2" "A3" "A3"
```

To use the next value to fill NA:

```
# Fill with next non-NA Value
VERINDEX_VEC <- c(NA,"A1","A2",NA,NA,"A3",NA)
VERINDEX_VEC
# [1] NA   "A1" "A2" NA   NA   "A3" NA  

non_na_positions <- which(!is.na(VERINDEX_VEC))
# Never need the first position of the vector if we are looking-ahead...
index <- ifelse(non_na_positions[1]==1,2,1)

for(i in 1:length(VERINDEX_VEC)){
  if(is.na(VERINDEX_VEC[i])) {
    VERINDEX_VEC[i] <- VERINDEX_VEC[non_na_positions[index]]
  } else {
    index <- index + 1
  }
}

VERINDEX_VEC
# [1] "A1" "A1" "A2" "A3" "A3" "A3" NA
```

Comment: Thank @Adam Sampson, I liked your approach, but there was no significant gain in time. Still around 3hrs, it just saved me few minutes.

Comment: Then I suspect you're going to need to use some sort of c-optimized vector operation. Don't have any better ideas that only use base. Normally I would've used zoo package as someone else recommended.

Answer (score 1):

First I will generate random data to test this

```
# generate random data 
test_data <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rnorm(100))
# add random NAs
test_data$y[sample(1:100, 50)] <- NA
```

Now try this:

```
# locate non NAs in the wanted column
not_na <- which(!is.na(test_data$y))

# define the function replace_NAs_custom

replace_NAs_custom <- function(i, col){
         if(is.na(col[i])){
           col[i] <- col[max(not_na[not_na < i] )]
         }
         return(col[i] )
       }

test_data$y_2 <- unlist(lapply(1:nrow(test_data), replace_NAs_custom, test_data$y))
```

Comment: thank you @DN_UNI but it did not matter what I tried your code was slower than mine and always gave me an error.

Comment: Glad to see that you have found your answer, however I'm curious to know, what was the error?

Comment: I was getting a 300gb result that eat all my memory and could not save the vector at the end when I tried with 200K row of data, and it was taking around 30 min to do that much, which at the moment with my code it takes around 4-5 min.
It worked fine when I used with onle 100 rows thou, but still slower than my code and the code from the answer above.
I still do not find the solution I need. It still takes around 3 hrs when tested on a 3 million row data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may have found  a faster way, at least a lot faster than my last answer, however I couldn't compare it with your code, since I couldn't reproduce the output.

(see below for the Benchmarking results)

Can you try this:

```
set.seed(223)
# generate random data 
test_data <- data.frame(x = 1:1000, y = rnorm(1000))
# add random NAs
test_data$y[sample(1:1000, 500)] <- NA



# which records are filled
not_na <- which(!is.na(test_data$y))

# calculate the distance from the previous filled value
# this is to identify how many times should each value be repeated
dist <- unlist(lapply(1:(length(not_na) - 1), 
                        function(i){
                          not_na[i+1] - not_na[i]
                        }))

# compine both to create a kind of "look-up table"
not_na <- data.frame(idx = not_na, 
                       rep_num = c(dist, nrow(test_data) - not_na[length(not_na)] + 1))

test_data$y_3 <- unlist(lapply(1:nrow(not_na), 
                                 function(x){
                                   rep(test_data[not_na$idx[x], "y"], times = not_na$rep_num[x])
                                 }))
```

The Benchmarking :

`f1()` is the last answer

`f2()` is this answer

- For 100.000 rows in test_data

  ```
  # microbenchmark(f1(), times = 10)
  # Unit: seconds
  #  expr      min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
  #  f1() 39.54495 39.72853 40.38092 40.7027 40.76339 41.29006    10


  # microbenchmark(f2(), times = 10)
  # Unit: seconds
  # expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  # f2() 1.578852 1.610565 1.666488 1.645821 1.736301 1.755673    10
  ```
- For 1.000.000 rows the new approach needed about 16 seconds

  ```
  # microbenchmark(f2(), times = 1)
  # Unit: seconds
  # expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  # f2() 16.33777 16.33777 16.33777 16.33777 16.33777 16.33777     1
  ```

Comment: Smart code mate. But I am getting this error "_Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1820.6 Gb_" I at this point I am using R for one part of my operation and then SQL for this part. Thank you thought. I have been reading and it seems that R is not that friendly on memory allocation when it has to deal with strings.